# Issue in drawing graph using CorePlot

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, core-plot

I wanna create a log based app for which am trying to make a graph that shows activities based on 24 hrs time. One hour has to be split into four(15 mins). I have tried using core plot for the same. I have attached the code i have done so far and the graph i have got till now.

```
 const CGFloat majorTickLength = 20; // height of the major tick
const CGFloat minorTickLength = 8.0;  // height of the minor tick
//    const CGFloat titleOffset     = self.titleSize;

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
CGRect bounds = hostingView.bounds;
#else
CGRect bounds = NSRectToCGRect(hostingView.bounds);
#endif

// Create graph
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
[self addGraph:graph toHostingView:hostingView];
[self applyTheme:theme toGraph:graph withDefault:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme]];

graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blackColor]];

// Plot area
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop    = self.titleSize;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = self.titleSize;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft   = self.titleSize;
graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight  = self.titleSize;
graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

// Setup plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@1440.0];
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0 length:@20.0];

// Line styles
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;

CPTMutableLineStyle *majorTickLineStyle = [axisLineStyle mutableCopy];
majorTickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
majorTickLineStyle.lineCap   = kCGLineCapRound;

CPTMutableLineStyle *minorTickLineStyle = [axisLineStyle mutableCopy];
minorTickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0;
minorTickLineStyle.lineCap   = kCGLineCapButt;

// Text styles
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleTextStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
axisTitleTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";


CPTMutableNumberSet *majorTickLocations = [NSMutableSet set];

for (int i = 60; i <= 1440; i += 60)
{
    [majorTickLocations addObject:@(i)];
}

CPTMutableNumberSet *minorTickLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
for ( NSUInteger loc = 0; loc <= 1440; loc += 15 )
{
    [minorTickLocations addObject:@(loc)];
}


// Axis1
CPTXYAxis *axis1 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
axis1.plotSpace          = graph.defaultPlotSpace;
axis1.labelingPolicy     = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axis1.orthogonalPosition = @1.0;
axis1.tickDirection      = CPTSignPositive;
axis1.axisLineStyle      = axisLineStyle;
axis1.majorTickLength    = majorTickLength;
axis1.majorTickLineStyle = majorTickLineStyle;
axis1.minorTickLength    = minorTickLength;
axis1.minorTickLineStyle = minorTickLineStyle;
axis1.majorTickLocations = majorTickLocations;
axis1.minorTickLocations = minorTickLocations;
// Axis2
CPTXYAxis *axis2 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
axis2.plotSpace          = graph.defaultPlotSpace;
axis2.labelingPolicy     = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axis2.orthogonalPosition = @2.0;
axis2.tickDirection      = CPTSignPositive;
axis2.axisLineStyle      = axisLineStyle;
axis2.majorTickLength    = majorTickLength;
axis2.majorTickLineStyle = majorTickLineStyle;
axis2.minorTickLength    = minorTickLength;
axis2.minorTickLineStyle = minorTickLineStyle;
axis2.majorTickLocations = majorTickLocations;
axis2.minorTickLocations = minorTickLocations;
// Axis3
CPTXYAxis *axis3 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
axis3.plotSpace          = graph.defaultPlotSpace;
axis3.labelingPolicy     = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axis3.orthogonalPosition = @3.0;
axis3.tickDirection      = CPTSignPositive;
axis3.axisLineStyle      = axisLineStyle;
axis3.majorTickLength    = majorTickLength;
axis3.majorTickLineStyle = majorTickLineStyle;
axis3.minorTickLength    = minorTickLength;
axis3.minorTickLineStyle = minorTickLineStyle;
axis3.majorTickLocations = majorTickLocations;
axis3.minorTickLocations = minorTickLocations;
// Axis4
CPTXYAxis *axis4 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
axis4.plotSpace          = graph.defaultPlotSpace;
axis4.labelingPolicy     = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
axis4.orthogonalPosition = @4.0;
axis4.tickDirection      = CPTSignPositive;
axis4.axisLineStyle      = axisLineStyle;
axis4.majorTickLength    = majorTickLength;
axis4.majorTickLineStyle = majorTickLineStyle;
axis4.minorTickLength    = minorTickLength;
axis4.minorTickLineStyle = minorTickLineStyle;
axis4.majorTickLocations = majorTickLocations;
axis4.minorTickLocations = minorTickLocations;

CPTMutableAxisLabelSet *axis4LabelSet = [NSMutableSet set];

for ( NSUInteger i = 1; i < 24; i++ )
{
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)i]
                                                      textStyle:axis4.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.tickLocation = @(i*60);
    newLabel.offset       = axis4.labelOffset + axis4.majorTickLength;

    [axis4LabelSet addObject:newLabel];
}
axis4.axisLabels = axis4LabelSet;



// Add axes to the graph
graph.axisSet.axes = @[axis1, axis2, axis3, axis4];
```

[image: Current Output]
In my above code i was able to use majorTickLocations to represent each HOUR and minorTickLocations to represent the 15 mins interval. But my desired output is the like the following image. Each 30 mins mark should be shown different too. How can i achieve this.[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 0):

Add one more horizontal axis. On the four existing ones, use the minor tick marks for the 15 minute intervals and the major ticks for the 30 minute intervals. On the new axis, set the major grid lines (drawn at the `majorTickLocations`) on the hour intervals. You don't need any tick marks on the new axis.

Comment: Can u show some light on how to set majorGridLines with some sample code pl?

Comment: I mean, how to specify the locations of majorGridLines

Comment: i.e how to specify the value for the property axis5.majorGridLines ?

Comment: Grid lines are drawn at the tick locations. Set the corresponding line style to make the grid lines appear. There are lots of examples in the *Plot Gallery* app.